# Fluctuating string in AdS black hole

Tags: black-holes, string-theory, ads-cft, quark-gluon-plasma

People frequently use fluctuating string in AdS black hole (see [1](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0605158),[2](http://arxiv.org/abs/0901.2338),[3](http://arxiv.org/abs/0812.5112) etc) to study dynamics of a "free external quark" in quark-gluon-plasma (QGP) at finite temperature. The background black hole geometry induces a black hole in the string world sheet. Many interesting results about the boundary theory can be obtained, at least qualitatively, just studying the Nambu-Goto action.

My question is : Why do people usually choose just *one* of the transverse spatial directions along which the world sheet can fluctuate? Suppose there is a background magnetic field in addition. Shouldn't one need at least two spatial  directions for the world sheet to fluctuate to observe/study its effect on the "quark"?

EDIT : Please look at the paragraph just below equation (2.7) in ref-[1](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0605158). The authors are considering only one coordinate namely $x$ which is non-vanishing. This is the *only* direction along which the string world sheet can fluctuate.

Comment: This was flagged as *unclear what you're asking*, but given that there are already *three* references linked in the question what this is about, I'd be interested to hear the reasoning behind it.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I don't know why it is unclear.. may be I should pin point a region of any of those references which contains my doubt.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I have edited my question. Hopefully this will help in understanding my doubt.